# Two images next to eachother with caption that spreads over the entire page

Tags: graphics, two-column

I want to put two images next to eachother in a two-column layout. I do this by:

```
\begin{figure*}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfigure[SGD classifier with modified huber loss when using the crowdsource-label-set. A=`anger', F=`fear', J=`joy', L=`love', S=`sadness', S2=`surprise', T=`thankfulness']{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{sgd_crowdsource_dataset.eps} \label{confusion_matrix_crowdsource}}\quad
  \subfigure[SGD classifier with modified huber loss when using the hashtag-label-set. A=`anger', F=`fear', J=`joy', L=`love', S=`sadness', S2=`surprise', T=`thankfulness']{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{sgd_hashtag_dataset.eps} \label{confusion_matrix_hashtag}}
  \caption{Confusion matrices}
\end{figure*}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

These images tend to stick in the middle and the captions only spread under the images themselves. This results in the two images taking up a lot of space. Is there a way to align these image left and spread the caption better ?

---

Edit:

With the subcaption package:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{SGD classifier with modified huber loss when using the crowdsource-label-set. A=`anger', F=`fear', J=`joy', L=`love', S=`sadness', S2=`surprise', T=`thankfulness' \label{confusion_matrix_crowdsource}}
[.49\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{sgd_crowdsource_dataset2.pdf}}
\subcaptionbox{SGD classifier with modified huber loss when using the hashtag-label-set. A=`anger', F=`fear', J=`joy', L=`love', S=`sadness', S2=`surprise', T=`thankfulness' \label{confusion_matrix_hashtag}}
[.49\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{sgd_hashtag_dataset2.pdf}}
\caption{Confusion matrices}\label{animals}
\end{figure*}
```

Gives this result:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `scale`, but something like `width=0.49\textwidth, keepaspectratio`.

Comment: Why not using the [`subcaption` Package?](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)

Comment: Following up on @MarioS.E.'s comment: The `subfigure` package which you appear to be using is considered deprecated (see e.g. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure), and the use of either `subfig` or `subcaption` is recommended instead.

Comment: @MarioS.E. I tried your suggestion (see the edit). It looks better though the caption of both figures are very close together now. If I change the size the captions will stay close together, though the figures will both come closer to the middle. Any idea how to keep the captions away from eachother ?

Comment: Adding a \hspace worked. Ok that seems to fix it. @MarioS.E. If you want you can set this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Ojtwist I just made a suggestion... If you feel like it, you can answer your own question and I'll upvote it.  That way you can get a little more rep points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Mario S. E., the subcaption package is the solution:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{SGD classifier with modified huber loss when using the crowdsource-label-set. A=`anger', F=`fear', J=`joy', L=`love', S=`sadness', S2=`surprise', T=`thankfulness' \label{confusion_matrix_crowdsource}}
[.45\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{sgd_crowdsource_dataset2.pdf}}
\hspace{20pt}
\subcaptionbox{SGD classifier with modified huber loss when using the hashtag-label-set. A=`anger', F=`fear', J=`joy', L=`love', S=`sadness', S2=`surprise', T=`thankfulness' \label{confusion_matrix_hashtag}}
[.45\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{sgd_hashtag_dataset2.pdf}}
\caption{Confusion matrices}\label{animals}
\end{figure*}
```

In order to make sure the captions of the figures do not touch, a hspace can be added